# R data.frame as a container for objects of multiple classes

Tags: r, list, dataframe, class, oop

I want to use a `data.frame` as a container to store multiple objects of specific classes, each row of the `data.frame` is an object in certain class，as shown below

```
a <- constructor_a(x=1, y=2, z='t')
b <- constructor_b(x=3, y=5)
c <- constructor_c(y=11, u=TRUE, w = 'st')

mycontainer <- make_container(a, b, c)
mycontainer
##  x    y    z    u    w
##1 1    2    't'  NA   NA
##2 3    5    NA   NA   NA
##3 NA   11   NA   TRUE 'st'

class(mycontainer)
## "data.frame"

class(mycontainer[1, ])
## "class_a"

class(mycontainer[2, ])
## "class_b"

class(mycontainer[3, ])
## "class_c"
```

As an initial step, I have tried this:

```
make_container <- function(...) {
    dots <- list(...)
    out <- rbind(...)
    for (i in seq_along(dots)) {
        class(out[i, ]) <- class(dots[[i]])
    }
    out
}
```

So given

```
a <- data.frame(x=1, y=1.5)
class(a) <- c('data.frame', 'class_a')
b <- data.frame(x=2, y=2.2)
class(b) <- c('data.frame', 'class_b')
c <- data.frame(x=2, y=2.2)
class(c) <- c('data.frame', 'class_c')
```

I would like to have

```
mycontainer <- make_container(a, b, c)
mycontainer[1, ] %>% class() # returns "data.frame" "class_a"
mycontainer[2, ] %>% class() # returns "data.frame" "class_b"
mycontainer[3, ] %>% class() # returns "data.frame" "class_c"
```

However, the fact is all three rows have the same class as `"data.frame" "my_class_a"`.
Is there a solution to fix this? Further more, is there a more generic solution to avoid restriction and assumption that each object is implemented as a `data.frame`? Maybe something as simple as:

```
mycontainer <- list(a, b, c)
class(mycontainer) <- "data.frame"
# of course this does not work, but I expect there exists some simple and generic solutions
```

When I check the base type of a `data.frame`, I see it is actually implemented internally in R using `list`:

```
a <- data.frame(x=1, y=1.5)
typeof(a) # returns "list"
```

Thus I believe there shouldn't be anything fundamental to prevent me using `data.frame` as a generic container instead of `list`.

Comment: R dataframes are lists of columns, not rows. Could you perhaps describe your problem in more general terms? Does the container absolutely have to be a data frame?

Comment: @DmitryZotikov I need a dataframe as the container. The reason is later the data.frame methods will ease my work a lot. Also information stored in this structure is easier to consume by the users than a nested list (considering the individual object is already a list). The tricky thing is to retain the individual object's class. I could just use `dplyr::bind_rows` to convert the nested list to a data.frame, but then I lose the class information for each individual object

Comment: Yes, exactly. If you only need the `[` getters and setters, you could probably re-define them for your custom S3 class, as well as `print`. This won't work if you need the full power of tidyverse, though :(

Comment: The structure you are describing simply isn't a data frame, and trying to coerce it into one is going to be very problematic. It is technically possible, but would still require defining a new S3 class that inherits from data.frame and would probably require its own versions of many of the generic methods. It would be far better to do this from scratch using an S3 class based on row-wise lists. Perhaps a use-case to demonstrate why you think having your structure as a data frame would allow us to see the problem more clearly?